General question on principal component analysis subject to by an incorrect mean
Suppose a probability density function over $\mathbb R^d$.
Let its expectation be $\boldsymbol{\mu}$, and some erronous estimate of it $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}} = \boldsymbol{\mu} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$.
If we performed a PCA process using $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}}$ instead of $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ (eigendecomposition of $\mathbb E[(\mathbf x - \tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}})(\mathbf x - \tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}})^T]$) - how is the result affected? Would the vectors be of different directions than the true principal components calculated using $\boldsymbol{\mu}$?
I have found no literature on this intriguing problem.
Intuitively, the vectors' directions would be the same as the true PCs, and only the projected variances are affected.

If you write it in matrix form, you will notice that the perturbation introduce a rank-1 correction of norm $|\epsilon|^2$ to your exact symmetric PSD matrix. The PCA of a PSD symmetric matrix coincides with its eigendecomposition, so you are asking how the eigenvectors change under a small rank one correction. There is a lot of literature about that, just to say one, look up Bauer-Fike's theorem for eigenvectors

If you write it in matrix form, you will notice that the perturbation introduce a rank 1 correction of norm ${\left\| \epsilon \right\|}_{2}$ to your exact symmetric PSD matrix.
The PCA of a PSD symmetric matrix coincides with its eigen decomposition, so you are asking how the eigenvectors change under a small rank one correction.
There is a lot of literature about that, just to say one, look up Bauer-Fike's theorem for eigenvectors.
Remark: Turning @Exodd's comment into an answer.
